# Xamarin Android: How to customize navigation bar to include a "next" button

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

In a swift Google search, I do find a couple of similar questions to pointing to Xamarin Forms. I need to do this in Xamarin.Android. [This documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/controls/navigation-bar/) talk about the Xamarin Android navigation bar but it doesn't say if it even possible to customize it. Which is the right approach for me to make a custom navigation bar with back and next buttons??

Thank you

Comment: There is a way to complete it. Hide the `Navigation bar`, and then put a layout which contains back and next buttons. The system's navigation bar, you can change its background, you can change its icon, but you can't remove/add button( So far, I don't know how to complete it except change the navigation bar's file in rom).

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with Xamarin.Core so you can Google without specifying Xamarin. You will have a small extra work to "convert" the **Java** code to **C#** code.

Here for example a tutorial to create a custom Action Bar for Android : 
https://www.journaldev.com/9952/android-custom-action-bar-example-tutorial

Don't forget that Xamarin is just a wrapper that allows you to create Android application using C# language.

**All the Android framework is available and you can use it.**